# AutoMapper set null if DestinationMember has Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a asp.net core API, that maps from DB entities to ViewModels.
Some of the properties in the ViewModels should only be delivered to users with the admin role. Not only the value of the property but the property itself.

given the customer entity in the DB

```
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

and the ViewModel

```
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public int? Priority { get; set; }
}
```

When the Controller is serialising to JSON, it will look like this if Priority has a value

```
{
    "name": "Customer Name",
    "priority": 1
}
```

and like this, if Priority is null

```
{
    "name": "Customer Name"
}
```

In the Map i need to check whether the Property has the JsonIgnore Attribute and if the User is in the Administrators Role. If the User is not in the Administrators Role and the Attribute is set, it should Map null.

Is there a way to loop through all Properties of the Destination and check for Attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use [IValueResolver<in TSource, in TDestination, TDestMember>](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html) interface:

```
public class CustomerViewModelPriorityResolver: IValueResolver<Customer, CustomerViewModel, int?>
{
    // As an example, if you have something similar
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;
    
    public CustomerViewModelPriorityResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // You can use DI to inject whatever service you need.
        // If, say, you have a UserRepository and you want to query the database
        _userRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<UserRepository>();
    }

    public int? Resolve(Customer source, CustomerViewModel destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // determines whether the property has the [JsonIgnore] attribute
        bool isJsonIgnore = typeof(CustomerViewModel ).GetProperty("Priority").GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>() is not null; 
        
        // If you want to query the database to get the user and his role (something similar)
        var user = _userRepository.GetByName(source.Name);
        var isAdmin = ...
        // Continue with whatever logic you have

        return // the value of 'Priority'; NULL or source.Priority;
    }
}
```

And in the mapping Profile:

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
     public MapperProfile()
     {
          CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
             .ForMember(customerVM => customerVM.Priority, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomerViewModelPriorityResolver>());
     }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Since you want to do the same thing for many properties, there is another option. [IMappingAction<in TSource, in TDestination>](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#using-imappingaction)

```
public class CustomerViewModelAction : IMappingAction<Customer, CustomerViewModel>
{
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

    public CustomerViewModelAction (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // DI
        _userRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<UserRepository>();
    }

    public void Process(Customer source, CustomerViewModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Using DI, perform your querying logic to determine the role
        var isAdmin = ...
        
        if(isAdmin) {
            // I don't know what you want to do if the user IS admin, but I'm assuming you just want to continue with the normal mapping
            return;
        }   
            
        var ignoredProperties = typeof(CustomerViewModel).GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>() is not null);
        foreach(var pi in ignoredProperties)
            pi.SetValue(destination, null);
    }
}
```

And the mapping profile:

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
     public MapperProfile()
     {
          CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
             .AfterMap<CustomerViewModelAction>();
     }
}
```

**TIP:**

Avoid doing DB calls in mapping. Suppose you want to map `List<Customer>` to `List<CustomerViewModel>`. You will end up with N-database calls.

You could instead add a property to `Customer: bool IsAdmin` and populate it beforehand, when you are fetching data about the customer.

Comment: Thank you! But my problem is, that I don't want to have that many places where i have to take care of that. When I add another Property to Customer/ViewModel, I want to only add the [JsonIgnore] Attribute and not add another ValueResolver and so on. Thats why I think I need a way to loop through the Properties. Maybe ForAllMembers or something can work, but I didn't figure it out yet.

Comment: You want to leave NULL only if [JsonIgnore] is present, or also the role check?

Comment: Also the role check. I used DI before with IMappingAction, so thats what i am struggling with less. looping through each property and check whether it has the attribute is my bigger problem. Since if it doesn't have the attribute, it should use AutoMappers default behaviour.

Comment: @MariusSteinbach You're struggling with reflection, I guess...Check now?